# Selenium Scraping Question | breaking out text block to list

Tags: python, selenium

I'm building a scraper to pull data from autotrader.co.uk and putting it into a data frame. I have a loop for pagination but one particular element is giving me a headache as I keep getting a line of text, not a list. how do I go through these and add them to their appropriate data buckets?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
import time

PATH = "/Users/csongordoma/Documents/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?postcode=SW1A1AA&radius=1500&include-delivery-option=on')
data = {}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Price', 'Title', 'Size', 'Key Specs', 'Year', 'Photo Count', 'attention-grabber', 'Description', 'URL'])

listings = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.search-page__result')
for listing in listings:
    data['Price'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('section.product-card-pricing')[0].text
    data['Title'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('h3.product-card-details__title')[0].text
    data['Key Specs'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('ul.listing-key-specs')[0]
    df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)


print(df)

driver.quit()
```

the culprit is the following line:

```
 data['Key Specs'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('ul.listing-key-specs')[0]
        df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
```

and the output if I print data['Key Specs']:

*'Key Specs': '2016 (16 reg) Hatchback 38,718 miles 1.0L 68PS Manual Petrol 1 owner ULEZ'*

Since the HTML is an  could I cycle through them? The issue with that is that in some cases one of these data points are missing, so everything will be skewed (in the place of the horse power data we'll just have the transmission type). See below the format. Any help is massively appreciated!

```
<ul class="listing-key-specs">
                <li>2009 (58 reg)</li>
                <li>Saloon</li>
                <li>174,000 miles</li>
                <li>2.0L</li>
                <li>177BHP</li>
                <li>Manual</li>
                <li>Diesel</li>
                <li>4 owners</li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the list you need iterate li element.

```
data['Key Specs'] =[li.get_attribute('innerHTML') for li in listing.find_elements_by_xpath('.//ul[@class="listing-key-specs"]//li')]
```

Is that you are after?